# recursion in traversing a binary tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, recursion

I am trying to do the leetcode problem problem #113, which is "Given a binary tree and a sum, find all root-to-leaf paths where each path's sum equals the given sum"

My problem is why does my code #1 shown below prints the values of all nodes in the tree? How does the recursion stack work in code #1 as opposed to how the recursion stack work in the code #2, which is a correct solution?

Thank you so much for helping me!

```
#code #1
class Solution:
    def pathSum (self, root, sum):
        self.res = []
        self.dfs(root, sum, [])
        return self.res
    def dfs(self, root, sum, path):
        if not root:
            return 
        sum -= root.val
        path += [root.val]
        if not root.left and not root.right and sum == 0:
            self.res.append(path)
        self.dfs(root.left, sum, path)
        self.dfs(root.right, sum, path)
```

```
#code #2
class Solution:
    def pathSum (self, root, sum):
        self.res = []
        self.dfs (root, sum, [])
        return self.res 
    def dfs (self, root, sum, path):
        if not root:
            return 
        sum -= root.val
        if not root.left and not root.right and sum == 0:
            self.res.append(path + [root.val])
        self.dfs(root.left, sum, path+[root.val])
        self.dfs(root.right, sum, path+[root.val])
```

Comment: This question seems to be open-ended and quite imprecise. Write down some examples and test your code on them. It should give you some outlook on what your code is exactly doing.

Comment: @fulaphex Hi thank you for your interest in this question! I would gladly write down some examples and test my code on them. But the problem is I am not exactly sure how the recursion stack works with this code so I could not test it.

Comment: I could suggest two approaches:
1. Write down some example trees on a piece of paper and analyse the code on the piece of paper.
2. Implement the missing class for the node, write down example trees and analyse the program with a debugger or some debug print statements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the comments above are well deserved, some examples would help here.  For instance, you talk about printing, but there are no print statements here, so how are you driving this and how are you using this?

Having said that, I suspect the problem will trace back to the fact that Code#1 changes the value of path, while code #2 does not.  Now if path was a number, this wouldn't matter because it would be passed in by value.  However, you passed in [] originally (an empty list) which is an object . . . so it is passed in by reference.  As a result, as code #1 proceeds you keep changing the node (path) above you, but in Code #2, the passed in paths never change.

Comment: I would like to call/remember that python is "call-by-object". See https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/. This `path+[root.val]` creates a new object.

Comment: Point taken.  After my 10th language, I sometimes get sloppy in my presentation.  Don't even get me started about UNDEF, NUL, NULL, None and 0.  <wink>